# Python re: Why doesn't it match?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the simple expression as below. Basically I want to match the string `[\` but seems like I have done something wrong. Please let me me know how to do it right.

```
print re.match("\[\\", "\[\\")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

Thanks

Comment: You should pretty much always use raw strings for regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barmar commented, you should always use [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) when you're dealing with regular expressions. If you don't, bad things happen. Observe:

```
>>> print '\[\\'
\[\
>>> print r'\[\\'
\[\\
```

The first one isn't a valid regular expression - a `\` must be followed by something in any regex. The second one, on the other hand, *is* a valid regex - specifically, it matches the literal character `[` followed by a literal `\`.

```
>>> re.compile(r'\[\\', re.DEBUG)
literal 91 # '['
literal 92 # '\'
```

You have another problem, too. The second argument to `re.match` (the string you're trying to match in) isn't what you think it is. Keep in mind that in *ordinary strings*, `'\['` isn't an escape code or anything - it is literally a backslash forwarded by a left bracket. Thus, the regex `r'\[\\'` won't match it, because it won't find a left bracket at the beginning of the string. You should either use `re.search`:

```
>>> print re.search(r'\[\\', r'\[\\').group()
[\
```

Or it might be that what you actually want is this:

```
>>> print re.match(r'\[\\', r'[\\').group()
[\
```

Remember that you have to escape end-of-string backslashes even in raw strings.